# What is the need for custom implementation of the GrantedAuthority and UserDetails in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been trying to learn Role Based Access Control of Spring Security. I have a question I can't find satisfactory answers to.

We can simply add roles to user using the default User implementation of UserDetails interface. Also we can restrict access to API endpoints using:

1. @Secured to secure access by discretely named roles.
2. @PreAuthorize which can also take Spring Expression Language(SpEL).

I can't find examples to reason what benefit do we get for configuring everything manually to do something which is already inbuilt.

PS: Please feel free to ask clarifying questions if there is something vague in my question.

Comment: If you don't need it, just don't use it.